# ffmpeg - Hyperthreading causes "Conversion failed" with multiple parallel instances

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract images from multiple videos in parallel, using `ffmpeg`.
Here's my bash script:

```sh
for video in *.MOV; do
    base=`basename "$video" .MOV`
    ffmpeg -i "$video" -r 0.02 "$base"/out_%02d.png > logs/"$base" 2>&1 &
done
```

When running this (on 60 videos), I check the `logs/` files and 40 of them have crashed at the beginning with the following error:

> Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
>
> Conversion failed!

However it works fine with a smaller amount of videos (around 5, even on videos that didn't work before).

**EDIT**: I tried to disable hyperthreading and it works fine now. Why is hyperthreading causing `ffmpeg` to fail ?

Comment: I did too with the same command, and it works fine. I forgot to mention it in my question, sry (edited the question)

Comment: Workaround: Since you said it works for smaller sets, you could process the files sequentially. This will take longer but should succeed. Remove the trailing `&`.

Comment: It should indeed, but I work on an HPC server with around a hundred cores, it's kind of a reflex to use parallelism :)

Comment: I tried disabling the hyperthreading and it solved the problem, it works fine now (but I'm not sure why). What's the policy for that kind of questions ? Should I write an answer and accept it, even without explanation ? Or leave it open ?

Comment: If you are interested in the actual reason, edit the question to be of the form *»Why does hyperthreading cause ffmpeg to fail«*, and wait for an answer. However, if you only care about a working solution, answer yourself and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

The secondary "hyper" thread is probably usually getting stuck in the ready-to-execute state because the executing thread's stream processing doesn't need to pause to wait for more data to come in. Without disabling hyperthreading, adding `-threads 1` to your ffmpeg command may help with the parallelized usage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But isn't the idea of a processor to periodically switch context between all threads ? In addition , why would that cause an error, as the other thread could just "wait for its turn" to be executed